# Calculated columns with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm familiar with SharePoint Designer and have just moved to using Visual Studio.  I am building a SharePoint Add-in here. I can't figure out how to add a calculated column into lists, however. The option simply isn't there. Advice, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own calculated column field definition, and then include that field in the list definition/schema (along with the other fields used in the calculation, of course).

The CAML for a calculated column looks roughly like this:

```
<Field ID="{900A6481-2EA0-4F7A-922D-F9596E0BF05F}"
       Name="MyCalculatedField"
       DisplayName="My Calculated Field"
       Type="Calculated"
       ResultType="Number"
       Group="My Columns">
  <Formula>=SUM([OtherColumn], [YetAnotherColumn])</Formula>
  <FieldRefs>
    <FieldRef Name="OtherColumn" />
    <FieldRef Name="YetAnotherColumn" />
  </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

The key things to see here: the `Type` is `Calculated`, you will need to specify the `ResultType`, you can include the formula using the `Formula` child element, and you need to include `FieldRef`s for every other field you are using in the calculation.

Here is the MSDN documentation on the [Field element schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979575.aspx).